# Change textarea of froala wysiwyg to notebook

Tags: css, froala

i'm trying to change the background image of froala wysiwyg editor to look like a notebook,

but it not changing anything at alll...could someone please help me fix it and show me how?

this is what i'm doing:

```
<style type="text/css">

textarea.notebook {
      font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      font-weight: 700;
      width: 100%;
      padding: 5px 0px;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      resize: vertical;
      font-size: 11px;
      line-height: 24px;
      border-bottom: 2px solid;
       -webkit-appearance: none;
      border-radius: 0;
      background: url(notebook.png);
}


</style>

<section id="editor">

    <form>
      <textarea  id="edit"  name="edit" class="notebook"  style="margin-top: 30px;">

  </textarea>


    </form>

  </section>
```

Comment: Probably what is happening is that the froala jQuery script is changing the background properties of the `textarea`, thus overriding your style rule.

Comment: What can i do to avoid that ?

Comment: Disclaimer: I have never used froala (but thank you, your question brought it to my attention).  Your best bet might be to email the froala support team and ask them.  There may be some configuration option.  My guess is that there is a style sheet in froala and you might be able to override the specific rule that styles the textarea block.  You may need a very specific selector.   I have done similar things in the past styling widgets like email sign ups and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible approach is to create a custom theme to the froala editor, see:

http://editor.froala.com/examples/color-themes

I suspect that if you can modify the background color, you can also add a background image.

Comment: Thanks i will try to find a way

Comment: Please add comment if you get it to work, forala seems to be a nice editor, I will take a look at it. All the best!